# Save plots as a picture in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, matlab-figure, som

I'm trying to get some images from neural network function in matlab. One of the functions that I'm using is:

**plotsomplanes(net)**

I could not find anyway to automaticlly save the plot in a PNG file.
Thanks in advance for any help or idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It will save the figure in you current working directory. See the documentation of `saveas`  [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html)

```
close all;
figure('visible','off');
plotsomplanes(net);
saveas(gcf,'filename','format'); %// in this case format is png
close
```